# Show only default color swatches using JQuery MiniColors

Tags: jquery, color-picker

I'm searching around the internet but can't find what I am looking for. Do you guys know if it's possible or have you tried this [colorpicker](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/)? What I'm trying to do is just display the selected color swatches and not the square like canvas colorpicker? Any guide will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In the documentation http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/#settings they have this array on your defaults that could contain up to 7 colors  rgb(a) or hex format. 

 swatches: []

Comment: @CarlosMartins, Yeah, I tried that one but it's not showing. `swatches: ["blue", "red"],`

Comment: Did you try rgb(a) or hex values? rgba(255,0,0,1) or #FF0000

Comment: I tried hex but no luck

Comment: Hey @CarlosMartins, it worked now. I'm using the old version. I updated it to the latest one and it worked! Thanks for the time :)

Comment: @claudios did you find out how to hide the picker?

Comment: @BrianLeishman including the input box? you can create a custom box that when clicked, it displays the color picker. see [here](https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/) and look for input modes.

Comment: @claudios I meant like hide the color choosing portion and just show the swatches at the bottom